# "ji" ending on verb "nai" stem?

Tags: verbs, conjugations, auxiliary-ず

My question is from this sentence.  It is from the "Easy Japanese" YouTube videos:

> 秋雨や我がすげみのはまだ濡らさじ

Why "nurasaji"? I would understand "mada nurasanai" - not yet wet - but why "ji"?

Comment: That's 'easy Japanese'? I think I'll give up now. I understand almost none of that sentence.

Comment: Please don't give up!  I don't know that I would call the videos "Easy" - but the conversations are short, with real people, and the captions are in kanji, romaji, and english, and of course you can pause them.  Disclaimer: not associated with the videos in any way.

Comment: +1 for the haiku.

Comment: Related / duplicate question: [Why じと instead of ず in その機を逃さじと?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/74658/why-%e3%81%98%e3%81%a8-instead-of-%e3%81%9a-in-%e3%81%9d%e3%81%ae%e6%a9%9f%e3%82%92%e9%80%83%e3%81%95%e3%81%98%e3%81%a8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

じ is an archaic auxiliary, similar to まい describing negative volition.

http://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa009021.htm

So it's まだ濡らすまい or まだ濡らさないようにしよう in modern Japanese.

Comment: thank you!  This was driving me crazy!  I've heard of the negative volitional so this helps!

Comment: 語源的には、この「～じ」が「～まい」の古形「～まじ」の後半になっているようです。