# Why じと instead of ず in その機を逃さじと?

Tags: auxiliaries, auxiliary-ず

> 硝煙で、鏑木肆星氏の姿は完全に覆い尽くされてしまう。その機を逃さじと、二匹のバケネズミが突進した。

I think その機を逃さじと means "not letting their chance slip away". But why isn't it just その機を逃さず?

Comment: https://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa009021.htm (I think)

Comment: In that case, it might be similar to その機を逃すまいと or その機を逃さないようにして

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46552/5010

Comment: See also [the じ entry in the 国語大辞典【こくごだいじてん】](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%98-515282#E7.B2.BE.E9.81.B8.E7.89.88.20.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.9B.BD.E8.AA.9E.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E5.85.B8), courtesy Kotobank.  This gives basically the same meaning as Darius's link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

じ is used to form negative volitional with 未然形 in classical Japanese so just treat it as 終止形 plus まい (◍•ᴗ•◍)❤